# How to fix "cannot read property of addEventListener of null" in my code?

Tags: javascript

I am learning vanilla JavaScript and using event delegation here. 
I get 'TypeError - cannot read property of addeventlistener of null' message on console and the function variable shows that it isn't in use.

```
var setupEventListener =  function (){

document.querySelector(DOM.container).addEventListener('click', 
ctrlDeleteItem );     /*this is the line which shows the error*/ 

};

var ctrlDeleteItem = function(event) {

console.log(event.target);

};
```

DOM.container is the object containing the properties which represents the classes used in JS from HTML.
For example here - var DOM = {container: '.container clearfix' };

This is the HTML part of the project -

```
<div class="container clearfix"> /*this class is selected for the event delegation*/
                <div class="income">
                    <h2 class="icome__title">Income</h2>

                    <div class="income__list">

                        <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Salary</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 2,100.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Sold car</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 1,500.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="expenses">
                    <h2 class="expenses__title">Expenses</h2>

                    <div class="expenses__list">

                        <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Apartment rent</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 900.00</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">21%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Grocery shopping</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 435.28</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">10%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: That means `document.querySelector(DOM.container)` is `null`, which means there is no matching element. Post a [mcve] for more information.

Comment: what is the value of `DOM.container`

Comment: @melpomene  I have added the HTML part too in the question now. DOM.container is the object which contains the class as a property.

Comment: Instead of `DOM.container`, `.container` will work i guess. Please see querySelector docs.

Comment: @JaromandaX  I have added the HTML part too in the question now. DOM.container is the object which contains the class as a property.

Comment: Again, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: you're possibly executing the code before the DOM is laoded - is this code in the head or the body above the HTML you've shown?

Comment: also, it seems odd you only want to attach a listener to the first `<div class="item clearfix" id="income-0">` ... may as well use `#income-0` as the queryselector

Comment: As @JaromandaX has mentioned, try putting your script tag at the very end of the body

Comment: @JaromandaX the script tag is in the bottom in the body of HTML.

Comment: @JaromandaX I want to get listener for both income and expense from one listener. That's why i put it in the parent element of both.

Comment: @SumanKundu the script tag is in the bottom in the body of HTML

Comment: `this class is selected for the event delegation` no, it isn't `'.container clearfix'` targets NOTHING, you want `'.container.clearfix'`

Comment: @JaromandaX It is now working.Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.container clearfix` is not a valid selector. It should be `.container.clearfix`. Please review your example after the update.

```js
var DOM = {
  container: '.container.clearfix'
};

var setupEventListener = function() {
  document.querySelector(DOM.container).addEventListener('click',
    ctrlDeleteItem); /*this is the line which shows the error*/

};

var ctrlDeleteItem = function(event) {

  console.log(event.target);

};

setupEventListener();
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix"> /*this class is selected for the event delegation*/
  <div class="income">
    <h2 class="icome__title">Income</h2>

    <div class="income__list">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, Pablo ! It works fine now.